# Flood fill with bitwise operations

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have a bit map stored as a (fixed) number of unsigned integers, e.g:

```
1 0 0 1
1 0 1 0
1 1 0 1
0 1 1 0
```

...is stored as the integer array `[ 9, 10, 13, 6 ]` (top-down, most significant bit on the left).

I would like to implement a flood-fill algorithm. For instance, if `m` is the map depicted above, `floodFill(m, 3, 2)` should produce the map:

```
1 0 0 0
1 0 0 0
1 1 0 0
0 1 1 0
```

(Here, `3,2` corresponds to third row (0-indexed), second column (from the right). The answer would be encoded as `[ 8, 8, 12, 6 ]`.)

I can certainly implement one of the standard approaches, but I wonder whether I can do better using bit manipulation tricks.

For instance, if part of the solution is contained in a map `m0`, I think I `m0 | ((m0 >> 1) & m)` "grows" the flood fill to the right.

Is this a standard trick to parallelize flood fill on bit maps? Can anyone come up with a complete algorithm? Prove interesting bounds on running time?

*Edit*: some additional examples:

```
floodFill ( 0 0 1 1     , 1, 1 ) =  0 0 1 1   
            1 1 1 0                 1 1 1 0
            0 0 1 1                 0 0 1 1
            1 1 0 1                 0 0 0 1

floodFill ( 1 0 0 1     , 1, 2 ) =  0 0 0 0   
            0 1 0 0                 0 1 0 0
            0 1 0 1                 0 1 0 0
            0 0 1 1                 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your example because you mention third row 0-indexed (i.e. the last one) which is untouched?

Comment: @Joky The output is the set of `1` bits from the input that are reachable from the position `3,2`. The last row is untouched because both `1` bits are reachable.

Comment: Ok now it is clear. When I see the proposed answer I was not the only one to have it wrong :)

Comment: no this is not a good approach because on flood fill you need start sub recursion on any new point. so what you will gain on speed by bit manipulation while line fill then much more time is lost by its decomposition for row fill sub recursions

Comment: @Spektre You can't escape recursion entirely, but the hope is that with bit manipulations, you can look at *all right neighbours* with a single operation, etc.

Comment: @Philippe I meant if you do this as universal approach then the time spend on extracting info about which recursion points should be called and which not is usually greater then the time saved by bit-shift approach of the line fill. (At least that is my experience) of course if yo use just a few cases like only one bit set or none bit set or use BYTEs and TAB all 256 possibilities that would speed thing up. Well you can prove me wrong by benchmark classical and bit-shift approach. Could be interesting to compare the speeds ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following works:

```
std::vector<unsigned> floodFill(const std::vector<unsigned>& map, unsigned int row, unsigned int column)
{
    std::vector<unsigned> res(map.size() + 2); // Add 'border' to avoid special case

    res[1 + row] = (1u << column) & map[row]; // Seed point (column: right to left)

    std::vector<unsigned> last;
    do {
        last = res;

        for (std::size_t i = 0, size = map.size(); i != size; ++i) {
            res[i + 1] |= (res[i] | res[i + 2] | (res[i + 1] << 1u) | (res[i + 1] >> 1u)) & map[i];
        }
    } while (last != res);
    res.pop_back();         // remove extra border.
    res.erase(res.begin()); // remove extra border.
    return res;
}
```

Test it: (I use C++11 here)

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const std::vector<unsigned int> v = {9, 10, 13, 6};
    const std::vector<unsigned int> expected = {8, 8, 12, 6};
    std::vector<unsigned int> res = floodFill(v, 3, 2);

    assert(res == expected);
    assert(floodFill({3, 14, 3, 13}, 1, 1) == std::vector<unsigned int>({3, 14, 3, 1}));
    assert(floodFill({9, 4, 5, 3}, 1, 2) == std::vector<unsigned int>({0, 4, 4, 0}));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This looks pretty good! I'm just wondering how you can use `res[i]` as opposed to `last[i]` when you compute the contribution from previous rows, as you're updating the same rows in the loop.

Comment: Nevermind, it looks like since the changes are monotonic anyway, it is not a problem. You may even save an iteration here or there.

Comment: @Philippe: It s true that I propagate directly changes from `row[i]` to `row[i + 1]` in the same loop, but it is not a problem, I see it as an optimization.

Comment: BTW, I think the code may be improved (avoid to compute unchanged rows at each loop for example, use a better method to see if there is a change that a vector compare and copy...).

Comment: Probably, though in my concrete use case, the rows are in fact the bytes of a single 64bit unsigned. I can compute all shifts in just 8 instructions, and comparison is just one instruction.